n8n does not allow changing workflow name
I am trying to deploy n8n with this docker compose and although the services start fine, n8n does not let me modify the name of the workflow, I have looked for options in environment variables but I cannot find it, I don't know if I am missing some permission or if it is due to .

version: '3.1'

services:
  n8n:
    image: n8nio/n8n:latest
    ports:
      - "80:5678"
    environment:
      - N8N_ENCRYPTION_KEY=smlaortrtj
      - N8N_SECURE_COOKIE=false
      - N8N_BASIC_AUTH_ACTIVE=true
      - N8N_BASIC_AUTH_USER=n8n_user
      - N8N_BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD=xxxx
      - N8N_PROTOCOL=https
      - WEBHOOK_URL=https://midomain
      - DB_TYPE=postgresdb
      - DB_POSTGRESDB_DATABASE=postgres
      - DB_POSTGRESDB_HOST=postgres
      - DB_POSTGRESDB_PORT=5432
      - DB_POSTGRESDB_USER=n8n_user
      - DB_POSTGRESDB_SCHEMA=public
      - DB_POSTGRESDB_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - n8n_data:/home/node/.n8n
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  postgres:
    image: postgres:16.2
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=n8n_user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  n8n_data:
  postgres_data:

It allows me to create workflows, execute, delete, but it does not allow me to change the name

